# Does Boost 1.64 support HP-UX?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, boost, hp-ux

I read about the platform that boost supports on the boost homepage. However, I do not know if it supports HP-UX.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html#log.installation.supported_compilers

Supported compilers and platforms.
The library should build and work with a reasonably compliant compiler. The library was successfully built and tested on the following platforms:

Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7. MSVC 8.0 SP1, MSVC 9.0 and newer.
Linux. GCC 4.5 and newer. Older versions may work too, but it was not tested.
Linux. Intel C++ 13.1.0.146 Build 20130121.
Linux. Clang 3.2.

Does that mean it supports HP-UX?

Comment: I'am trying to building Boost C++ libraries on a variety of operating systems and archictures. First, I wonder if it is possible to compile on HP-UX.

Comment: With GCC or aCC?

Comment: @PaulFloydI'll compile C++ source with G++ (GCC 6.X).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, as can be seen in:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/config/platform/hpux.hpp